# Detecting onload for object constructor

Tags: javascript, object, onload

I am wondering if there is a way of detecting when an object is loaded.

Something like that:

```
var Square = function(){
    this.width = 100;
    this.height = 100;

    //Onload would go here.
    this.onload = function(){
        console.log("Square loaded successfully!");
    }
}

//Creating a new square.
var object1 = new Square();

//When the object1 i loaded, the console log returns: "Square loaded succesfully!".
```

I know i can just put my code after my properties, but i really need the onload to be "stored" as one of the properties.

Comment: You'll have to explicitly call the `onload` method within the constructor: `this.onload()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use this code that `Square` is initialized or not

```
object1.hasOwnProperty('width');
```

return true if `Square` has been loaded/initialized otherwise return false.

OR

If you want to do it by method then use.

```
var object1 = new Square();
object1.onload(); //call this method for check loaded or not
```

Comment: Wow. By reading your comment, I realised how easy the answer was. I totally didn't think about it. Thanks!